# GridView Images is not loading

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have gridview and have to download images to gridview. When I open app I cannot see any images, but I think my code is somehow correct. How to fix it?
I use this code in my adapter:

```
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        //float wd = 250 / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        //float hg = 300 / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int pxwd = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 90, Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics());
        int pxhg = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 120, Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics());
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(pxwd, pxhg));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromURL(GridViewConfig.getImage_list().get(position)));
    return imageView;
}


// references to our images
private Drawable LoadImageFromURL(String url)
{
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        return Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and here is url list:

```
public class GridViewConfig {
public static ArrayList<String> image_listGrid = new ArrayList<String>();

public static ArrayList<String> getImage_list() {
    return image_listGrid;
}

public static void setImage_list(ArrayList<String> image_list) {
    GridViewConfig.image_listGrid = image_list;
}

public static void addImageUrls(){
    image_listGrid.add("someimage.jpg");
}
```

But problem is no image is showing on my GridView.

Comment: Can you first confirm whether images are getting downloaded or not

Comment: use picasso for loading your images

Answer (score 0):

In your `getView(...)`, you should use `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP` replaces `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP`:

```
int pxwd = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 90, Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics());
int pxhg = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 120, Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Hope this help!

Comment: no, it's not a solution. It doesn't matter DIP or SP.

Comment: Yes, I have. And nothing changed.

Comment: Could you try put other image from your `drawable` to `imageView.setImageDrawable`, to make sure `getView` is working